# Can i hide the line "powered by instamojo"?

Tags: instamojo

I create a payment link using instamojo. But when it is loading it shows a line  "powered by instamojo" at the bottom of the payment link. Is there anyway to hide that text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to hide this line by using this app:

https://www.instamojo.com/apps/details/com.instamojo.remove_branding/

(This link is only accessible when you're logged into your Instamojo account)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any app or pay anything to remove it. If you are a developer , you can remove it simply by downloading the `im-embed.min.js` script and comment out the line below

```
function o(e) {
    return true;
    // c(e).parent(".im-checkout").append('<a href="https://www.instamojo.com?partner=remote" target="_blank" title="Powered by Instamojo" class="im-powered-link">Powered by Instamojo</a>')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes , exactly as a developer we don't need to work on any instamojo app as such , all we need to do is 
extract this link from the script file what instamojo guys provide https://d2xwmjc4uy2hr5.cloudfront.net/im-embed/im-embed.min.js by loading this link in browser the script file  "im-embed.min.js" will be downloaded , after that you can copy this file to your local folder and start making changes as per your requirement, in the developer console

similary you can work on stylesheet by extracting the link from im-embed.min.js